# How do X-Lasers interact with Ricochet Shot?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, firearms

When using the [Ricochet Shot Deed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/ricochet-shot-deed-grit/) to alter the effective range and apparent firing position of a character armed with an [X-Laser](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/technological-weapons/), does the wielder deal damage in the whole line of fire or just the second half of the ricochet shot? (I assume that the character deals damage in a line from the ricocheted square through the target, not from the character, but please correct me if I'm wrong about that).

Comment: Whoever designed that really screwed up. That thing should've been a Line attack with a Reflex save, because it really does not work as a proper weapon.

Answer (score 4):

This might be a really pedantic reading of the rules, but Ricochet shot says:

> You can fire a shot at a wall or piece of solid terrain,

And X-laser says:

> When making an attack with an x-laser, make a single attack roll and compare that result to the ACs of **all creatures** in a line extending out to the weapon’s maximum range.

Which suggests that you cannot fire the X-laser at a wall or solid piece of terrain; you can only point it in a direction and hit creatures with it.

Which seems to fit thematically with what the X-laser is. And whomever designed it screwed it up, because it should have been a Line attack with a Reflex save. It doesn't make sense as an attack roll and it mechanically doesn't interact with just about any rule on ranged attacks properly.

Answer (score 3):

The [X-Laser](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/technological-weapons/#TOC-X-Laser) weapon actually changes the default behavior of [ranged attacks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#ranged-attacks) and has a specific rule on how the weapon works. So [ricochet shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/ricochet-shot-deed-grit/), which is an ability designed with firearms in mind (not lasers), shouldn`t even apply.

> When making an attack with an x-laser, **make a single attack roll** and compare that result to the ACs of all creatures in a line extending out to the weapon’s maximum range. This weapon damages all targets with an AC equal to or lower than the attack roll.

The weapon does not allow you to attack any creatures in the normal sense of attack actions, you point the weapon in their direction and hope to beat their *touch armor class*. I would go as far as to say that the weapon works more similarly to a [line magical effect](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lightning-bolt) than a ranged weapon attack.

This weapon is so incredibly overpowered that if you roll a natural 20 and confirm, which isn't difficult being a *touch* weapon, you will be dealing critical x4 against all creatures caught in the line.

Comment: Actually, I could see occasions where you could confirm against only some of your targets, if they had different touch AC.